# My function doesn't change value of variable

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my code doesn't change it's value

```
let gameIsRunning = false;

const start = document.getElementById('start-game');
start.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function startGame() {
  return gameIsRunning = true;
}

console.log(gameIsRunning); // still false after click start-game
```

There is actually slightly more code inside, but I made it shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to `click` on the `start-game` element. Remove the return part from the function and put the `console.log` inside the function.

```js
let gameIsRunning = false;

const start = document.getElementById('start-game');
start.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function startGame() {
  gameIsRunning = true;
  console.log(gameIsRunning);
}
```

```html
<p id="start-game">Click</p>
```

Comment: oh my bad question. I do click the start-game element but still false.

Comment: It is working. See the example. Maybe this is not all parts of your code

Comment: Yea I dont know what magic lies here, after I question it. it works. thanks man